# AS3 | for create global variable

Tags: variables, for-loop, actionscript, var

How to make FOR to create global variables ?

```
function processXML(e:Event):void {
    for (var i:int=1; i <= 7; i++) {
        var str_(i):String = ('str' + (i));
        trace ('str: ' + i);
    }
}
```

Output console exmaple:

```
str: 1
str: 2
str: 3
str: 4
str: 5
str: 6
str: 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Variables declared inside for loops should not be used outside of the scope.
2. Workaround. If you need, let's say 7 variables why not to store them inside an global array?

   ```
   private var _variables:Array = [];

   function processXML(e:Event):void 
   {
       var str:String;

       for (var i:int=1; i <= 7; i++) 
       {
           str = new String();
           str = 'str' + (i).toString();
           _variables.push(str);
           trace ('str: ' + i);
       }
   }

   function getVariable(index:int):String
   {
       return _variables[index] as String;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do exactly? I am not sure what you want but I would create somewhere an object(or Array,Dictionary) and in the for loop I append the variables generated.Having all those generated objects inside a object/collection will make it easy to manage them.So try making a class, add a static member that is an Array or Dictionary and add soem static methods for appending new objects(that are generated in the for loop)